# AWS SSM マネージドインスタンスに出てくる条件

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2

SSM agent の設定がしてある EC2 の AMI から
新たに EC2 インスタンスを作成したのですが
SSMマネージドインスタンスに出現せず
`aws ssm start-session`
を実行しても
`An error occurred (TargetNotConnected) when calling the StartSession operation`
となってしまいます

AMIコピーで全く同じ構成のはずなのに SSM が使える使えないの差はなぜ生じるのでしょうか

Comment: ネットワークまわりやインスタンスプロファイルなどに差異がありませんか？

Comment: VPCサブネットは同じでしたが EC2Role をつけるのを忘れていたようです！　ありがとうございます！

Comment: ご自身で回答を書き、解決済みにしていただけたらと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2Role に同じ Role を設定し、
さらにインスタンスを再起動したところ
システムマネージャーから見えるようになりました